# No write access inside chroot

Tags: linux, gcc, permissions, chmod, chroot

I got a chroot jail in which I 'd like to compile some files using GCC. The file system structure of the jail is the following (by the `ls` command)

```
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 May  8 20:49 bin
drwxrwxrwx 1 user root 4096 May  8 21:31 data
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 Apr 10 14:56 dev
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 Apr 15 16:33 etc
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 Apr 12 02:21 include
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 Apr 12 02:21 lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 Apr 12 02:22 lib64
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 Apr 12 02:22 libexec
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root 4096 Apr 12 02:22 usr
```

My file is located inside the `data` directory, which has all permissions for everyone enabled, and has name `source.c`. When I compile the file **inside the chroot**, but **as root user** everything goes fine, but when I use another userspec (e.g. nobody, or even the user with the username **user**) I get the following error

```
source.c:1:0: fatal error: can't open ./ccOQmimU.s for writing: Permission denied
 #include <stdio.h>
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

The procedure I follow each time to compile my file is

```
chroot command
cd data
gcc source.c
```

Could you please help me out with that?